# System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException: 'Name or service not known', Unable to Reach Exposed Port after Docker-Compose up

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, containers

I have a .NET Core solution with Docker, using a Dockerfile for build and release. The Dockerfile exposes port 80, and the docker-compose.yml creates two containers on the same network - one for PostgreSQL (postgres-db) and one for the .NET Core application (testapi).

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
services:
  testapi:
    depends_on: 
      - "postgres"
    container_name: testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8010:80"

  postgres-db:
    image: "postgres"
    container_name: "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345678
      - POSTGRES_DB=Test_Api
    expose: 
      - "5432"`
```

The issue arises when trying to access port 8010. Even after successful container creation and migrations, the page is not accessible. When attempting to run a build, a third container on a different network is created, resulting in an error due to the inability to find the postgres-db service.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // here where I am running the migrations
        DatabaseManagementService.MigrationInitialState(app);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json:**

```
"TestApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8010"
},
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://{ServiceHost}:8010/swagger",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true
}
```

Despite modifications in launchSettings.json and attempting to open the URL from Docker Desktop, the page remains inaccessible. Any insights into resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: One thing that might be confusing you is that launchsettings.json isn't used when running in a container. launchsettings.json is only used when running from an IDE like Visual Studio. Your app gets it's configuration settings from appsettings.json. It's important that `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Development` as Swagger will only be available in development mode by default.

Comment: Thank you for your info. Do you see any problem in that codes that let the testapi container unreachable.